# Class template deduction for a pointer to a datatype

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, type-deduction

I have the following wrapper class:

```
template <typename T>
class Remap {
  public:
    Remap(T *data, int *remap) : data(data), remap(remap){};
    T &operator[](std::size_t idx) const { return data[remap[idx]]; }
  private:
    T *data;
    int *remap;
};
```

It works perfectly fine if I call it like:

```
Remap<double> remap(data, remap);
```

where data is of the type `double *`. If I try to let the compiler (intel icc 15.0.3, with -std=c++11) deduce the template type:

```
Remap remap(data, remap);
```

It fails with the error message:

> `argument list for class template "Remap" is missing`

I try not to violate the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle and thus like to fix this issue.

Comment: Upgrade to C++17, which supports class template argument deduction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before *C++17* there is no deduction for class template arguments.

The workaround is to use some kind of `get_remap` template function which produces `Remap` objects:

```
template<typename T>
Remap<T> get_remap(T* data, int* remap) {
    return Remap<T>(data, remap);
}
```

and then use it like:

```
double* data = nullptr;
int* remap = nullptr;

auto remap_obj = get_remap(data, remap);
```

[**Example**](https://godbolt.org/g/mVmPeX)

Moreover, with *C++14* support `get_remap` might be shortened to:

```
template<typename T>
auto get_remap(T* data, int* remap) {
    return Remap<T>(data, remap);
}
```

by letting the compiler to deduce a return type.

---

Since *C++17* you might make use of [class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) and simply write:

```
double* data = nullptr;
int* remap = nullptr;

Remap remap_obj(data, remap);
```

[**Example**](https://godbolt.org/g/1b3nmS)

Comment: Ha, exactly what I was about to write, too, with one minor difference: `auto make_remap(...)`

Comment: @Aconcagua with `auto` it's even better :)

Comment: (+1) for `make_remap`, there are a lot of `make_...` functions out there designed more or less with the same intention, which makes their names kind of idiomatic.

Comment: @Aconcagua: function return type deduction requires C++14, though, and the OP currently uses C++11.